# Bind(....class).asEagerSingleton() is not working referenced in UntypedActor Play 2.5 java

Tags: playframework

I am using Play 2.5 Java.

The eager loading is not working for me when running my app packaged with "activator dist" or using "activator testProd" command. It only works with "activator run".

My singleton class is bound as eager singleton in Module class.

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(DataStaxUtil.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

In the actor class, the database session is returned as null.

```
public class AttendeeActor extends UntypedActor {

    private static Session session = DataStaxUtil.getSession();
    public static Props props = Props.create(AttendeeActor.class);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Throwable {
    ...
```

The error occurred with "activator testProd":

```
[info] application - DataStaxUtil->getSession session=null
Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[application]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:44)
    at akka.actor.NoArgsReflectConstructor.produce(IndirectActorProducer.scala:105)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:213)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:562)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:461)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:483)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at actors.AttendeeActor.<clinit>(AttendeeActor.java:29)
    ... 19 more
```

The DataStaxUtil.java is added:

```
package services;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

import play.Logger;
import play.inject.ApplicationLifecycle;

@Singleton
public class DataStaxUtil {

    private static final Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
    private static final String cassandraHost =     config.getString("datastax.url"); 
    private static final int cassandraPost= config.getInt("datastax.port");
    private static final String keyspace = config.getString("datastax.keyspace");
    private static Cluster cluster;
    private static Session session;

    @Inject
    private DataStaxUtil(ApplicationLifecycle lifecycle) {
        cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoint(cassandraHost)
            .withPort(cassandraPost)
            .withCredentials(config.getString("datastax.username"), config.getString("datastax.password"))
            .build();

        session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

        Logger.info("DataStaxUtil->DataStaxUtil session=" + session);

        lifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
            session.close();
            cluster.close();
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        });
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        Logger.info("DataStaxUtil->getSession session=" + session);

        return session;     
    }
}
```

What could I do to troubleshoot? Thank you!

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing DataStaxUtil implementation and where it is injected. Besides, show how you create the AttendeeActor.

Comment: The DataStaxUtil implementation is added to the original post.

Comment: It looks like some DB configuration problem in production mode. What is

Comment: Is session not null in the log message (in the DataStaxUtil constructor)? If it is null , it means there is some DB configuration problem for a production mode.

Comment: The session is null in the DataStaxUtil constructor. Is there something needs to be done for production mode for eager loading?

Comment: The eager loading is the same for production mode. Id you see that log message, it means, that constructor was called. But the session was not initialized. I suppose, that this happens due to  DB configuration problem in the production mode. Do you use hibernate? If yes, add also the persistence.xml to your question.